# Siri Shortcuts: "Use with Siri" not showing in settings. Can not allow Siri usage

Tags: ios12, siri, sirishortcuts

I have implemented Siri Shortcuts for an app. Everything works fine except for one thing:

When executing `INPreferences.requestSiriAuthorization` to request authorization for the usage with Siri, the user can allow or deny authorization.
In the case of a deny, the user should be able to allow Siri usage later in the settings.

But for my app, I have no "Use with Siri" option in the settings, like Whatsapp or Telegram have. How can I allow Siri usage as a user, after initially denying the Siri Authorization Request performed by the app?

Long story short:
How do I activate the "Use with Siri" in the settings, where a user can allow usage with Siri for my app?

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately not... however, I can use Siri in my app. But the whole Accept/Deny Siri Thing is somehow buggy from my point of view.

Comment: yeah I ended up not asking for permission at all... it still works. I suppose permission is for some other use of Siri that we don't know.

Comment: Should not be, as they want us to ask for permission. Anyway, I am happy for you and I hope that there won't be problems when you upload it to the App Store because you do not ask for permission. Or have you already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question on the Apple Forum, it has just been asked there.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/114750

Summarized: You do not need to request authorization for Siri when using Siri Shortcuts with custom intents. Further, you will not get the "Use with Siri" option in the settings when using custom intents.

> This option only shows up if you're using one of the SiriKit domains, such as workouts or bill pay.

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to remove the `NSSiriUsageDescription` string in your `Info.plist` file? If so, the option will disappear from your the Settings app.

Comment: I double checked and have the `NSSiriUsageDescription` in the `Info.plist` file of my iOS App.